# Error Number: 1064 in deleting data using Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mariadb, codeigniter-3

I want to deleting my data in the table, but i can't delete the data because of this problem. Error Number: 1064

This is my Controller

```
class Dosen extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent ::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('Dosen_model');
}
public function index() 
{
    $data['judul'] = 'Daftar Dosen';
    $data['dosen'] = $this->Dosen_model->getAllDosen();
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('dosen/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
public function tambah()
{   
    $data['judul'] = 'Form tambah data Dosen';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nip','NIP','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama','Nama','required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('dosen/tambah');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->Dosen_model->tambahDataDosen();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash','Ditambahkan');
        redirect('Dosen');
    }
}
public function hapus($nip)
{
    $this->Dosen_model->hapusDataDosen($nip);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash','Dihapus');
    redirect('Dosen'); 
}
```

And this is my Model

```
<?php
class Dosen_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function getAllDosen()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('daftar_dosen');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    public function tambahDataDosen()
    {
        $data = [
            "nip" => $this->input->post('nip'),
            "nama" => $this->input->post('nama'),
            "prodi" => $this->input->post('prodi'),
        ];
        $this->db->insert('daftar_dosen',$data);
    }      
    public function hapusDataDosen($nip)
    {
        $this->db->where('nip',$nip);
        $this->db->delete('daftar_dosen',$data);
    }
}
```

the output is :
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: models/Dosen_model.php

Line Number: 23

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\endtest\application\models\Dosen_model.php
Line: 23
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\endtest\application\controllers\Dosen.php
Line: 40
Function: hapusDataDosen

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\endtest\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

and then

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS NULL' at line 3

DELETE FROM `daftar_dosen` WHERE `nip` = '0001' AND IS NULL

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/endtest/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear

```
Message: Undefined variable: data
```

In other words, somewhere there is a variable `$data` that is not defined.

Where in your code is `$data` found? The answer: In the function `hapusDataDosen()` in the call to `$this->db->delete('daftar_dosen',$data);`

It is hard to know exactly what you are trying to do. My guess is all you need to do is change

```
$this->db->delete('daftar_dosen', $data);
```

to

```
$this->db->delete('daftar_dosen');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function hapusDataDosen($nip){
    $this->db->where('nip',$nip);
    $this->db->delete('daftar_dosen');
}
```

OR

```
public function hapusDataDosen($nip){
    $this->db->delete('daftar_dosen', ['nip' => $nip]);
}
```

Don't use `$data` because

1. You are not passing it to model function
2. It is unnecessary to delete a record from DB

Answer (score 0):

Try This -- 
In Model

```
public function hapusDataDosen($nip)
    {
        $this->db->where('nip',$nip);
        $this->db->delete('daftar_dosen',$nip);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function hapusDataDosen($nip){
    $this->db->delete('daftar_dosen',array('nip'=>$nip));
}
```

Comment: It's always best to add some explanation to your code rather than only writing the code itself. In your case you could describe how to use parameters as part of the `delete()` call.